# Suppressing parentheses in a function that uses the pipe operator

Tags: r

Can somebody explain why I have to suppress the parentheses for the function is.factor  in the command shown below? Student-data was read from a .csv file. I can see the structure of Student-data and I want to select only the factor variables. The command works fine but I cannot see why I cannot write the parentheses. I saw an example in the forum. Sorry if the question is silly or has been asked before. I could not find any similar question.

studentData%>%select_if(is.factor)

Comment: @akrun I guess OP is asking why cannot `studentData%>%select_if(is.factor())`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the pipe, `%>%`, that requires you to "drop the brackets, it's `select_if`.  From the documentation:

.predicate "A predicate function to be applied to the columns or a logical vector. The variables for which .predicate is or returns TRUE are selected. This argument is passed to rlang::as_function() and thus supports quosure-style lambda functions and strings representing function names."

You're not evaluating the function here.  You're passing an R object.  (Functions are objects, just as data.frames or scalars are).  The evaluation happens later, in the guts of `select_if`.  Including the brackets would tell R to evaluate the function at the time the `select_if` call was executed.  That's not correct.  It needs to be evaluated later.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense.